# Is there ever a valid reason to call pthread_yield() when running under a modern/pre-emptive scheduler?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

[pthread_yield](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html) is documented as "causes the calling thread to relinquish the CPU", but on a modern OS/scheduler, the relinquishing of the CPU happens automatically at the appropriate times (i.e. whenever the thread calls a blocking operation, and/or when the thread's quantum has expired).  Is `pthread_yield()` therefore vestigial/useless except in the special case of running under a co-operative-only task scheduler?  Or are there some use-cases where calling it would still be correct/useful even under a modern pre-emptive scheduler?

Comment: I suggested it a while back for a situation where a thread kept unlocking and relocking a mutex in a loop without giving other threads waiting on it a chance to run between, and boy did that piss people off...

Comment: Only constructive thing to come out of it was to prefer the standard `sched_yield()` instead, but that still didn't go over well.

Comment: @Shawn did adding the call appear to improve the program's behavior when you tried it out?

Comment: It helped reduce thread starvation in that case, yes. But because it's only well defined for the real time schedulers, results may vary. If you *need*  more robust fairly distributed locking, it's not the fix. If you just want to give the normal scheduler a hint it's free to ignore, eh, throw it in.

Comment: Not found one yet.....

Answer (score -1):

`pthread_yield()` gives you a chance to do a short sleep -- not a timed sleep. You relinquish the remainder of time slice to some other thread or process, but you don't put the thread in a wait queue.

Also a while ago I read about how schedulers prioritizing interactive processes. These are the processes that user interacts with directly and you feel their sluggishness most (you have less of a feeling of your system being slow if your UI is responsive). One of the properties of interactive processes is that they have little to do and mostly don't use entire time slice. So if a process keeps yielding before its time slice is up you assume it is interactive and you boost its priority. There were exploits that used this trick to effectively use 99% of CPU while showing the offending process as being at 0%.

Comment: 'One of the properties of interactive processes is that they have little to do and mostly don't use entire time slice.' Decoded from MSspeak, that means 'spend most of their time blocked on their input message queue'.

Comment: @MartinJames: I appologize if it affends you, but I got that from some research papers years ago, not MSDN. I figured if it was good enough for publication in a peer-reviewed paper then it might be good enough here.

Comment: lol, you got that from a peer-reviewed paper?  I appreciate 'years ago', but can you cite/link it?   BTW, I am not offended, as such, it's just that that language is grossly misleading, if not actually wrong.  Threads are not given 'time-slices' as a necessary property for their operation.  The timer interrupt is not necessary for a pre-emptive system, (though very useful for timing out system calls).  'time-slicing' can only happen when a system is overloaded such that the number of ready/running threads exceeds the number of cores available to run them.

Comment: Whoever wrote that original 'time-slice', 'quantum' rubbish has done a massive disservice to a generation of developers.  I see this on 'multithreading' all the time.  Just last week, a very respected, high-rep contributor was convinced that a Windows thread that became ready had to wait until the next 'time-slice' to run.  The phrases from the paper you described, and MSDN, are responsible for that warped view of modern multitasking kernels.

Comment: @ MartinJames: I don't think I have heard anyone but Microsoft talk about quanta. How do you implement preemptive system without timer interrupt? Without timer interrupt what you have is essentially the rubbish that was Windows 95 and older.

Comment: Oh, and I apologize if I came over as a bit arrogant but, unless some get up on soapboxes and shout, yet another generation of developers will be flushed down a quantum drain:)

Comment: No, no, I am always on the lookout for new stuff. I have been desensitized over the years. I've been trying to find the papers I originally got these ideas from, but I think these guys are talking about essentially the same thing (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6038593). But back to my previous question -- I have no idea how to implement preemptive multitasking without timer interrupt.

Comment: Hah.. 'How do you implement preemptive system without timer interrupt?' that, there, is my point!   Just don't implement a hardware timer interrupt.  The scheduler is then only entered upon syscalls and I/O completion interrupts.  You will argue that such a system is not practical because there is then no sleep,  no I/O timeouts, no effective  CPU resource management upon overload, (time-slicing:), but it is certainly possible.  There is no 'time-slicing' going on here as I write this - 1% CPU usage and 8 cores - no slicing happening:)

Comment: A better way of looking at these kernels is as a state-machine.  Its inputs/events are syscalls from already-running threads and interrupts from I/O peripherals like KB, mouse, disk, network and, if required, timer hardware.  It's outputs/actions are a set of threads running on cores:)

Comment: I like the idea. And as long as you have one less `while (1);` running than you have cores there's always someone to put those insolent loops in their rightful place. Thanks for not letting go and keeping this debate going.

Comment: I don't disagree with your characterization of the effect of `pthread_yield()`, but that doesn't quite seem to address the question of whether there is a valid reason to want that behavior.  The behavior of interactive processes doesn't quite seem relevant to that question either.  In fact, it goes the other direction, I think: is there a reason to yield if you anticipate blocking soon, instead?  If you have work to do, and you can count on the kernel pre-empting you as needed, then what benefit is there to yielding the CPU?